# What can I do to improve my question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, asking-questions

Can I ask for your feedback on how can I improve the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14738009/what-design-technique-is-appropriate-for-creating-a-webapp-with-interactive-popu ?

Comment: Unfortunately, by its nature the question is not suitable for [main]. You are asking for the best way to do something, though you are not providing enough constraints as well as making it overly broad.

Comment: Probably the best way forward is to actually try something. Code something. And then evaluate it. If you find particular shortcomings to your approach, you can make that specific situation the topic of a question.

Comment: Lesson learned! Are there any specific changes you'd suggest I made to this question or is it best being deleted/left as is?

Comment: Just leave it I'd say. Deletion at this point would only work against you. You don't seem to have enough rep to safely delete anything and not bump into a question ban at this point. Especially if there is other deleted content.

Comment: I see.
I'm sorry I posted a question so thoughtlessly, will remember to be more specific in the future.

Comment: Asking this question here at least shows you're not mindlessly going forward as some users tend to do. You'll be fine. Good luck.

Comment: *[Quora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora)* accepts these kinds of questions. Sample: *[What's the best file format to use on the web for images that will have transparent features (for example, corners)](https://www.quora.com/Web-Design/Whats-the-best-file-format-to-use-on-the-web-for-images-that-will-have-transparent-features-ie-corners)*

Comment: Cool! I'll give Quora a try the next time I'll have a broader question in mind.

Comment: Another example (an example of the dreaded list-of-X questions): *[What are the best Arduino tutorials?](https://www.quora.com/Arduino/What-are-the-best-Arduino-tutorials)*

Comment: Clearly I have to give some more thought deciding on when to post my questions. Thank you for pointing it out for me.